# Oracle ATP Wallet Connection

Tags: oracle, jasperserver

i am trying to connect Jasper server to Oracle ATP using the TNS file info in the wallet and receive connection error.

IO Error: Got minus one from a read call

Comment: follow directions here for your java (jdbc) apps https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-5ED3C08C-1A84-4E5A-B07A-A5114951AA9E

Comment: Thank you @thatjeffsmith, i went through the documentation and still could not connect. My settings look like this : jdbc:oracle:thin:@adb.sa-saopaulo-1.oraclecloud.com:1522:dbxxxx_high as the platform only asks for host, service & port, nevertheless i get error ---> Io exception: Got minus one from a read call

Comment: That error almost always indicates a ssl issue

Comment: from what i can tell, Jasper doesn't support it - they don't provide a mechanism to supply more than just the very basic connection properties - and that's not secure enough to access Oracle Autonomous